# appending anchor tag in django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

edit for clarity- this is a script tag in an html file

the working anchor tag-

```
      <a href="{% url 'comments:delete_question_comment' pk=comment.pk %}" title="delete" class="btn btn-simple">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger"></span>
        <span class="text-danger icon-label">Delete</span>
      </a>
```

my attempt at appending-

```
*dom node*.append("<a href='{% url \"comments:delete_question_comment\" pk=comment.pk %}'</a>")
```

the error- Could not parse the remainder: '\"comments:delete_question_comment\"' from '\"comments:delete_question_comment\"'

I'm not sure what's going wrong. the quote escaping should work as appending just

```
\"comments:delete_question_comment\"
```

works fine, so if anyone knows what the problem is I'd be greatly appreciative

Comment: You should remove backslashes and try again. The whole `{% url ... %}` tag will be converted into a URL even before it is merged to your Javascript code anyway.

Comment: if this append you are attempting is in a javascript file, it is not going to work

Comment: this is a script tag in an html file